# When I execute stamp()/clearstamps() in turtle(python), whether I need to update it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to implement a process like this

1. time.sleep(1)
2. display a red square with turtle.stamp()
3. time.sleep(1)
4. remove the red square with turtle.clearstamps(-1)

Here is my code:

```py
import turtle
import time

snakes = turtle.Turtle()
snakes.ht()
snakes.shape("square")
snakes.up()
time.sleep(1)
snakes.color("Red")
snakes.stamp()
# turtle.update()
time.sleep(1)
snakes.clearstamps(-1)
turtle.done()
```

When I run this code, the red square doesn't appear at all. It seems that the red square has been deleted by 'clearstamps()'. However, I take the step 3 to delay it for 1 second before deleting it.

With some trys, I find that if I add a update after I create a stamp (just the comment part of the program above), the program will work successfully, with the 1 second delay before deleting.

I wonder why I should add this update(), since I don't turn off my tracer in my program.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `time.sleep()` in turtle, as it can interfere with the event loop, and instead use turtle's own `ontimer()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def action():
    stamp = turtle.stamp()
    screen.ontimer(lambda: turtle.clearstamp(stamp), 1000)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color('red')
turtle.shape('square')

screen = Screen()
screen.ontimer(action, 1000)
screen.mainloop()
```